# Replace all URL's based on hostname using Apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, apache-2.4

I am setting up local testing environments for my team. Each of us have our own subdomain that points to our machines on our internal network. In the code, the URL's are all written with the `www` subdomain. I need to replace these subdomains with that of the box that the config lives on using only one config that all of us share.

I am currently running Apache 2.4 on all of the dev machines and using `mod_substitute` and `mod_headers` inside of conditional blocks to achieve this. Here is a sample of one of the virtual hosts using this configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerAlias nathans-dev.example.com robertr-dev.example.com justinb-dev.example.com
    ServerName www.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/example-errors.log"

    SetOutputFilter INFLATE;SUBSTITUTE;DEFLATE 
    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE application/json
    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE application/javascript

    <If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'nathans-dev.example.com'">
        Substitute "s|//www\.example\.com|//nathans-dev.example.com|iq"

        Header always edit Location "//www.example.com" "//nathans-dev.example.com"
        Header edit Location "//www.example.com" "//nathans-dev.example.com"
        Header edit Set-Cookie "domain=(?:www\.)?example\.com" "domain=nathans-dev.example.com"
    </If>
    <ElseIf "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'robertr-dev.example.com'">
        Substitute "s|//www\.example\.com|//robertr-dev.example.com|iq"

        Header always edit Location "//www.example.com" "//robertr-dev.example.com"
        Header edit Location "//www.example.com" "//robertr-dev.example.com"
        Header edit Set-Cookie "domain=(?:www\.)?example\.com" "domain=robertr-dev.example.com"
    </ElseIf>
    # ... SNIP ...
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that we are running Apache 2.2 in production. This is the last item preventing me from mirroring the production environment. The conditional `If` directive does not exists on 2.2 and I have tried many things to try and get it to work using 2.2 but no luck.

I have tried using a virtual host for each member of the team, using `Directory` blocks pointing to symbolic links for each member with the target pointed at the main web directory (e.g. `/var/www/nathans -> /var/www/html` with `<Directory "/var/www/nathans/>Substitutions...</Dirctory>`)

Is there any way to have conditional substitutions based on the virtual host or the hostname?